# Unable to install 1.x versions of Tensorflow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

The CPU I have doesn't have AVX instructions, so I'm forced to install versions of Tensorflow which are below 1.16. I'm using

`pip3 install tensorflow==1.15`

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have updated all the packages. I've even downgraded python to 3.6.9 but still I'm unable to install older versions of Tensorflow

Comment: There is no package available for tensorflow 1 and python3.8. Maybe recompiling an older python3 version could help ?

Comment: This procedure could help to get rid of SSL problems : https://towardsdatascience.com/building-python-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04-2ed29eec152b

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a virtual environment with "python 3.7"

python3.7 -m venv my_env

source my_env/bin/activate

then run the install command "pip install tensorflow==1.14"

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when `pip` is not up to date.

If you're using a virtual environment, use

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

If you're using the system interpreter, use this (`sudo` may be required):

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install tensorflow==1.15
```

Comment: My pip3 version is 20.1

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can try downloading tensor flow 2 using the link:-
illya13.github.io/RL/tutorial/2020/04/26/installing-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-20.html

Comment: As I wrote in my questions, anything above 1.16 is not support because my CPU doesn't have AVX instructions.

Comment: Some libraries like stablebaslines still requires tensorflow 1... and the problem remains.